# Automatically extracting multiple data frames from the list in R

Tags: r

I have a list with 52 elements. Half of the list elements are data frames with 6 columns and different number of rows. The remaining half of the elements are just lists each containing character and integer elements. I want to get all data frames from the list using custom made functions. Ideally, I want to extract all the data frames from the list as separate objects with unique names. I tried to automate it without any success using loops and if/else functions. The thing is, I need to automate this process as I will produce more lists containing 50 to 60 elements. Any suggestion would be most appreciated.

Comment: can you post an example of the data. Suggest taking a small sample and then using `dput` to output and post.

Comment: Consider also showing a small example of what you actually tried that was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

with `l` as your list:

```
classes.in.list=lapply(l,class)          # find classes in your list
idx=which(classes.in.list=="data.frame") # find indices of data.frames
mydfs=l[idx]                             # subset your list
data.table::rbindlist(mydfs,idcol=T)     # fast rbind with ID column (install data.table library)
```

Comment: `classes.in.list` in your case is a list. You can not use `==` between a list and a character., Also you could think of `Filter(is.data.frame,l)`

Comment: `==` works for me in the list. I like the `Filter` approach better though.